# Python BeautifulSoup returns empty text for an element, browser displays text, source code displays nothing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

If I run this code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/nut-and-seed-products/3071/1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

span = soup.find("span", id="NUTRIENT_0")
print(span.text)
```

I get nothing printed.

The Span tag contain text in chrome browser, but not in html source code.

How can I scrape this text?

Comment: the content is rendered via javascript, so one solution is to use something like selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data/json is embedded in the html comments. The other issue is the keys do not have the double quotes. So I used regex to add in the double quotes to take care of that. It's simply then just need to read that into a dictionary and can get whatever data you want out of that.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

page = requests.get("https://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/nut-and-seed-products/3071/1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all("script")
for script in scripts:
    if 'foodNutrients = ' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('foodNutrients =')[-1]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit('fillSpanValues')[0]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit(';',1)[0]
        jsonStr = "".join(jsonStr.split())

        valid_json = re.sub(r'([{,:])(\w+)([},:])', r'\1"\2"\3', jsonStr)
        jsonObj = json.loads(valid_json)

# These are in terms of 100 grams. I also calculated for per serving       
g_per_serv = int(jsonObj['FOODSERVING_WEIGHT_1'].split('(')[-1].split('g')[0])

for k, v in jsonObj.items():
    if k == 'NUTRIENT_0':
        conv_v = (float(v)*g_per_serv)/100

        print ('%s : %s (per 100 grams)   |   %s (per serving %s' %(k, round(float(v)), round(float(conv_v)), jsonObj['FOODSERVING_WEIGHT_1']  ))
```

**Output:**

```
NUTRIENT_0 : 565 (per 100 grams)   |   158 (per serving 1ounce(28g)
```

Comment: this doesn't work for other pages on the same domain like page = requests.get("https://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/vegetables-and-vegetable-products/2383/2")